# Set mantissa length and cut off digits

Tags: matlab, precision

I want MATLAB to behave like a floating point unit with (let's say) 5 digits, meaning that the mantissa is set to 5 digits.
Therefore I want to write a function that converts any number to the desired format, which I can apply after every arithmetical operation.

What it should do is normalizing the number to zero-point-something-times-ten-power-something, cutting off left over digits and NOT rounding them.

Important is that the number is not only shown that way, but stored with limited significant digits.

Examples:

```
d = 5; % 5 significant digits, meaning 5 digits mantissa
0.12345 = foo(0.123456, d)
0.12345e-1 = foo(0.0123456, d)
0.12345e+3 = foo(123.456789, d)
```

How does one do that? Is there any built-in MATLAB functionality that allows it?

Comment: you asked for builtin functionality, well MATLAB has a specific toolbox for this sort of thing: [Fixed-Point Designer](http://www.mathworks.com/products/fixed-point-designer/), not that I have experience with it..

Comment: @Amro: the user mentioned floating-point numbers and not fixed-point numbers. I'd rather see it as non-standard (IEEE754) floating point numbers that still have mantissa & exponent and not a fixed point representation. Or does the FP Designer also support that?